# Request route action return as zip file download like response in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, request, response

Hello I want setup the download zip file as response when someone request a action in symfony2. Please help me or provide me some code.

Comment: Possible duplicated: Http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268025/symfony2-create-and-download-zip-file

Comment: Thanks man but I need whole demo for that or some useful url for that.

Comment: Ok, so let me know what code you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a full demo here :
http://www.piotrbelina.com/symfony-2-sending-a-file-to-download-from-controller/